# Snort does not detect attacks when running in offline mode

Tags: snort, pcap

When I run Snort on a pcap file (that contains malicious traffic), it does not detect anything.

I uncommented the rules path in `Step #7` at `snort.conf`. Nothing is changed.

How to let Snort detect attacks from `test.pcap` and generate a `log` file?

I used the following command :

```
$ snort -r /home/mina/Download/test.pcap -c /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

Comment: Have you checked that your snort rules will alert on the malicious traffic in the pcap file?

Comment: Yes, I used a pcap file contains bad-login and the related rule_path are uncommented in the snort.conf.